# web3py - Function Call when Sender Must Be Certain Address

Tags: web3.py, python, eth-call

I have a contract on Ropsten, and when I do this is python, I get a result:

```py
result = contract.functions.getLastUpdateTime(0).call()
```

So I know the ABI is there, the address, etc.

There's another function `getCurrentPrice` on that same contract, which only differs in that it is restricted to be readable only for those querying with a certain address (ie, `require(msg.sender = '0x123...')`). I can get this to work in Remix, and have the public and private key that satisfies this restriction, so the problem is not that this function is screwed up.

Clearly, I need to tell it my public and/or private key info. Where do I add that to my transaction?

```py
with open(contract_abi0) as f:
    contract_abi = json.load(f)
    contract = w3.eth.contract(address = contract_address, abi = contract_abi['abi'])
UpdateTime = contract.functions.getLastUpdateTime(0).call() # works!
Price = contract.functions.getCurrentPrice(0).call() # does not work :(
```

Comment: You tagged this with web3js, but this looks like Python code.

Comment: A small advice: If it really is a read-only function, then don't bother imposing this restriction because with just a little effort, anyone can retrieve the information that this function returns (remember, everything on the blockchain is essentially visible).

Comment: definitely true in general, but there are cases where this is helpful, so I wish I could figure this out...

Answer (score 5):

Web3.py's `ContractFunction.call` method accepts a dictionary of transaction parameters in the same way as `ContractFunction.transact`.  For example, if you wish to call the method from `web3.eth.accounts[0]`:

```py
Price = contract.functions.getCurrentPrice(0).call({'from': web3.eth.accounts[0]})
```

Related links:

- [`ContractFunction.call` documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.call)
- [`web3.eth.sendTransaction` documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.sendTransaction) (explains transaction dictionary parameters)

Comment: works! Interestingly, it doesn't require the required eth address's private key, just the eth address, unlike when calling from another contract. I suppose this is because this call is outside the EVM.